# How to construct Schur-Weyl decomposition of independent and identically distributed mixed qudit states?

Tags: mathematics, resource-request

Given a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} \approx \mathbb{C}^{d}$ (i.e. a qudit system) if I have $N$ identical copies of a mixed state I can use Schur-Weyl duality to decompose the state as
$$
\rho^{\otimes N} = \left( U \rho_0 U^{\dagger} \right)^{\otimes N} = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \mathcal{Y}_{N,d} } p_{\lambda,N} \left( U^{(\lambda)} \rho_{0,\lambda} U^{(\lambda) \dagger}  \otimes \frac{I_{m_\lambda}}{m_\lambda}  \right)
$$
where $\mathcal{Y}_{N,d}$ is the set of Young diagrams with $N$ boxes and $d$ rows and $U^{(\lambda)}$ are irreps of $\mathrm{SU}(d)$, see, e.g., [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03542) for an explanation and an application in quantum information.

I know that it is possible to obtain a closed formula for the probabilities $p_{\lambda,N}$, as detailed in [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.527958), which if I understand correctly should be equivalent to use formulas for group characters.

However, I want to find the irreps $U^{(\lambda)}$ and the states $\rho_{0,\lambda}$. This should be equivalent to finding the so-called "Schur transform", a task for which a quantum algorithm exists, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407082) and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0601001) by Bacon, Chuang and Harrow.

I am still in the process of understanding and learning the maths, but in the meantime I am here to ask:

1. do you know of any available (classical) implementation of this (even if it's not efficient)? I.e. some algorithm that given $U$ and $\rho_0$ and $N$ gives all the $U^{(\lambda)}$ and $\rho_{0,\lambda}$.
2. is there some relevant reference where somebody **explicitly** computes this Schur-Weyl decomposition for a system that is **not** qubits (ideally with applications in quantum information)?